How to define custom entry point in expo file based routing?
i want to use the data from redux store at my root level, for that purpose i created a seperate entry file main.js as mentioned in expo documentaion but now my app isnot running?
Pleas help me to fix this
i tried

npx expo prebuild --clean
npx expo start -c

my main.js file
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Index from "./app";
import { store } from "./store/store";

function Main() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Index />
    </Provider>
  );
}

registerRootComponent(Main);


The screenshot of the error


UPDATE NOV 7 2024
i found out that for every small change in my redux code the whole application reloads, so i need to get ridoff main.js file and change may root layout file as below

i created a seperate component and wrapped that component in rootlayout file.

import { store } from "@src/store/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import MainLayout from "../components/MainLayout";

export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MainLayout />
    </Provider>
  );
}


*I had to discard below one to stop whole app reloading when there is a change in redux code *
i was able to solve the problem, by changing my main.js as follows.
as mentioned here github issue
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import { ExpoRoot } from "expo-router";
import { store } from "./store/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";



export function App() {
  const ctx = require.context("./app"); 

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ExpoRoot context={ctx} />
    </Provider>
  );
}

registerRootComponent(App);


